# Forcing updates on IOS

Tags: objective-c

Will apple reject an app for doing things like putting up a screen that says: "We've added lots of new features.You need to update before using this app..."? I'm unsure if this is a nosy thing to do but it may be something I need if I ever create lots of new features that need widespread frontend adoption.

Comment: No, they will not reject... There are lot of applications that do that... Big Games example is Clash of clans which do that...

Comment: Does anyone feel this could make you lose lots of users?

Comment: Like that were just too lazy to update?

Comment: no, you will not loose users just bcz of this...

Comment: You will not lose users because the fact that they need to update means they are *already* using your app.

Comment: Check out Harpy for a great framework that allows you to customize this behavior. You can choose to force updates for major version changes, or just inform users that a major/minor/patch has been released. I've used it on various projects in the past: https://github.com/ArtSabintsev/Harpy

Answer (score 3):

This is fine. Clash of Clans for example will not let you play if it detects a newer version on the Appstore. Many online-related apps need to be up to date.

Also, you don't need to force ***all*** updates. You could simply force critical updates only.

Comment: It should be noted though, that this is usually pretty annoying.

Comment: @EnricoSusatyo : Annoying only if you force users to download 4+ times in a month...

Comment: @FahimParkar That, and some people might not have unlimited fast internet all the time and prefer to update their apps at home, or want to just use the app immediately. If you really need a taxi and the taxi app wants you to update first, that's just dumb.

Comment: @EnricoSusatyo : there are plus and minus for this point... It can't be I am right or You are right... As per app need, we have to go ahead...